# What is the equivalent of `-analyze` in the new pass manager?

Tags: llvm

I'm working with the `opt` tool to manually run optimization passes on LLVM IR code, and I'm quite new to it. While running analysis passes, the sources I've been referring to used the `-analyze` flag with `opt` to perform analysis and print the results without transforming the input. However, with the version I have installed, `opt` warns me that the `-analyze` option is deprecated for the new pass manager.

Now I did find out that I can disable the new pass manager by using `-enable-new-pm=0`, and that works as expected. I can also use the new pass manager and discard the generated output by redirecting to `/dev/null`. However, I'd like to know if there is an official equivalent `-analyze` while using the new pass manager.

My searches seem to yield only two results of note - the [LLVM docs](https://llvm.org/docs/NewPassManager.html) and the [LLVM blog post](https://blog.llvm.org/posts/2021-03-26-the-new-pass-manager/) introducing the new PM. Neither of these seem to discuss the `-analyze` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent of `-analyze` in the new pass manager is

`--passes="print<your-analysis-pass-name>"`

Here is the example usage:

```sh
opt -load-pass-plugin examplepass.so --passes="print<examplepass>" -disable-output example.bc
```

Further information and details you can look this awesome github repository for llvm passes and their usages with legacy(old) and new pass managers: https://github.com/banach-space/llvm-tutor